# How to Update CKEDITOR text box while selecting dropdownlist in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I have CActiveForm in Yii inside this i displayed a dropdownlist and ckeditor message box. When i select any one of dropdown listed item this name should be displayed in message box.(i.e., on event/selection of dropdownlist it(the name of selected item) should be displayed in message box as well). Is there any way to do this in Yii. Please help to achieve this ?
The following code resides under protected/views/form

```
    <?php echo CHtml::activedropDownList( ScriptQuestion::model(),'crm_base_contact_form_field_id',$select_field); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'message', array('id'=>'question_editor','maxlength'=>508, )); ?>

    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'; ?>"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'question_editor', {   toolbar:'MA', height:'100px',width: '700px'  }  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a `CHtml::textfield` and update the textfield on drop-down ajax.

From this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/45990-dynamic-loading-data-in-selection-box/):

> First you can create the country drop-down list and call ajax

```
<?php
                echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_name', '', CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll('status!="2"'), 'id', 'venue_name'), array(
                    'id' => 'send_venue',
                    'prompt' => 'Select Venue',
                    'class' => 'col_165',
                    'ajax' => array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'url' => CController::createUrl('Getprovince'),
                        'update' => '#county_name',
                        'data' => array('county_id' => 'js:this.value'),
                        )));
                ?>
```

> and create the div

```
<div id="#county_name"></div>
```

> then after create the Getprovince function on your controller

```
public function actionGetprovince($id){
                 $county_id=$_POST['county_id'];
                $data=Provinces::model()->findAll("county_id='".$county_id."' AND status='1'");
                $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','provinces_name');
                echo "<option value=''>Select Event</option>";
                foreach($data as $value=>$event_name){
                        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($event_name),true);
                }
}
```

> more reference
>   [http://www.yiiframew...ist-using-ajax/](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is help to archive this  concept for me.

Place the following code in protected/views/forms  within CActiveForm widget

```
     <?php echo CHtml::activedropDownList( ScriptQuestion::model(),'crm_base_contact_form_field_id',$select_field,      
                array(
                'id' => 'send_bcfield',
                'class' => 'col_165',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('DisplayMessage'),                                                               
                    'update' => '#question_editor',
                    'data' => array('bcfield' => 'js:this.value'),
                    'success'=> 'function(data) {$("#question_editor").empty();
                            var selected = $("#question_editor").val(data);
                            CKEDITOR.instances.question_editor.setData(selected);
                            } ',

                'error'=> 'function(){alert("AJAX call error..!!!!!!!!!!");}'                
                    ),

                    )       
    ); ?>   

        <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'message', array('id'=>'question_editor','maxlength'=>508, )); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'question_editor', {   toolbar:'MA', height:'100px',width: '700px'  }  );
    </script>
```

This is Controller Action:

```
      public function actionDisplayMessage(){

$q = $_POST['bcfield'];
$model=ScriptQuestion::model()->findAll();

$sql = "SELECT name  FROM crm_field WHERE crm_field_id=". $q ;
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $result= $command->queryScalar(); 

    //echo CJSON::encode($result);
    echo "%".$result."%";
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

}